# Determining a symlink on unix system

Tags: c

I am trying to use the function S_ISLNK(file.st_mode) to check if a certain file is a symlink versus a directory or regular file. However it does not seem to work when I check it with a symlink file.

Here is my code:

```
            if(S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode))
            {
                // DIR - display files in the directory
                printf("    DIR         ");
                fileType = 2;


            }else if(S_ISLNK(fileStat.st_mode)){
                // LNK - display the name of the file the link is pointing to
                printf("    LNK         ");
                fileType = 3;
            }else{
                // Display general info only
                printf("    REG         ");
                fileType = 1;
            }
```

The check for a Directory is working fine, however when I run my program on a symlink file it shows up as a regular file. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat` stats the target of a link.  Use `lstat` if you want to tell whether a file is a symbolic link:

> `lstat()` is identical to `stat()`, except that if path is a symbolic link, then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.